# Flutter Test only works with pumping duration

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I have this widget:

```dart
class _DemoWidget extends State<DemoWidget> {
  Choices? _selectedChoice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          createTile(
              'The First Option', Choices.FRIENDS, const Key('firstOption')),
          if (_selectedChoice == Choices.FIRST)
            TextFormField(
              key: const Key('searchFirst'),
            ),
          createTile('The Second Option', Choices.CONTACT, const Key('secondOption')),
          if (_selectedChoice == Choices.SECOND)
            TextFormField(
              key: const Key('searchSecond'),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  RadioListTile<Choices> createTile(String title, Choices choice, Key key) {
    return RadioListTile<Choices>(
      key: key,
      title: Text(
        title,
      ),
      value: choice,
      groupValue: _selectedChoice,
      onChanged: (Choices? val) => setState(() => _selectedChoice = val),
    );
  }
}
```

It has two radio buttons and based on which button is currently active, it will render out a text field bellow that option. I am trying to create a test for this behavior and started with this:

```dart
  testWidgets('Clicking on person search opens up textfield',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      renderWith(),
    );
    Finder firstOption = find.text('The First Option');
    await tester.tap(firstOption);
    expect(find.byKey(const Key('searchFirst')), findsOneWidget);
  }, skip: false);
```

but would get a faild test every time, I then added a duration between the tap and the ensure Visible

```dart
  testWidgets('Clicking on person search opens up textfield',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      renderWith(),
    );
    Finder firstOption = find.text('The First Option');
    await tester.tap(firstOption);
    await tester.pump(Duration(milliseconds: 50));
    tester.ensureVisible(find.byKey(const Key('searchFirst')));
    expect(find.byKey(const Key('searchFirst')), findsOneWidget);
  }, skip: false);
```

and the test passes.

I think that using timeouts doesn't seem like a very safe way to do testing, but have read in some places that this is required for some flutter widgets. Is there some way to do this test without having to pump a time wait into the tester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/tap-drag#3-ensure-tapping-a-button-adds-the-todo), you just need to use `pump`:

```dart
Finder firstOption = find.text('The First Option');
await tester.tap(firstOption);
await tester.pump();
```

Comment: Wow I overlooked that in the documentation, thanks a lot! I've had a lot of edge cases similar to this and didn't realize that sometimes this was required.